# Retrieve latest record in Tera data

Tags: teradata, record

I have updated the question... need to write a query in Tera data to select only the latest record based on the suffix of the userid.

**CODE:**

```
SELECT USERID, DEPTNAME,LOCATION 
  FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEP 
 ON EMP.USERID =DEP.USERID;
  INNER JOIN LOC 
  ON LOC.DEPID =DEP.DEPID;
```

Output came up as:

```
USERID    DEPTNAME      LOCATION

123       SALES         SPAIN
123A      SALES         SPAIN
980C      RETAIL        GERMANY
980E      RETAIL        GERMANY
980T      RETAIL        GERMANY
657A      MARKETING     FRANCE
555       TEXTILES      KENYA
```

**Expected Output is as below:**

```
USERID    DEPTNAME      LOCATION  

123A      SALES         SPAIN
980T      RETAIL        GERMANY
657A      MARKETING     FRANCE
555       TEXTILES      KENYA
```

Please help.

Comment: Userids are based on digits 0-9 and the suffix is a a-z?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment userids are based on an optional initial letter followed by digits 0-9, the suffix is any letter:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
QUALIFY
   Row_Number()        -- optional letter followed by any series of digits
   Over (PARTITION BY RegExp_Substr(col, '\D?\d+')
         ORDER BY col DESC) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However , the userid’s can start with letters also… such as M123 , M123A, M123B. So the expected output is just “M123B”. Is there a way for this kinds to write the query ?

Comment: Added an optional letter to my answer

Comment: I used the Qualify function in my code. But am not able to see all the records as present in the Expected Outcome.                                                                                                                    
  SELECT USERID, DEPTNAME, LOCATION 
  FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEP 
 ON EMP.USERID =DEP.USERID;
  INNER JOIN LOC 
  ON LOC.DEPID =DEP.DEPID                                                                              
   QUALIFY
   Row_Number()      
   Over (PARTITION BY RegExp_Substr(USERID, '\D?\d+')
         ORDER BY DEPTNAME DESC) = 1;

Comment: Please let me know where am going wrong with the code. Otherwise, let me know an alternate way to achieve the Expected Output.

Comment: Please note: I have updated the question with the Query.

Comment: Don't know, the regexp should work for the example data. Can you show some of the missing rows?

Comment: Sorry my mistake … it’s actually displaying all the 7  records . Not just the 4 records present in the Expected outcome

Comment: That's impossible, `SELECT RegExp_Substr('980E', '\D?\d+')` returns `'980'` as expexted. Must be something else

Comment: Looks like my code had >1 and do everything was displaying

Comment: However by replacing it with =1 .. also not working .. I also have one “where condition to that query “… will that be the reason

Comment: Something like this :             SELECT USERID, DEPTNAME, LOCATION FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEP ON EMP.USERID =DEP.USERID; INNER JOIN LOC ON LOC.DEPID =DEP.DEPID   where date1=Timestamp ‘2022-01-01 00:00:00’              QUALIFY Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY RegExp_Substr(USERID, '\D?\d+') ORDER BY DEPTNAME DESC) = 1

Comment: Move the ROW_NUMBER to the Select-list and check what's returned